# Реализация появления/исчезновения элемента при скроле

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Помогите сделать эффект появления/исчезновение картинки в хедере при скролле к началу страницы/скролле вниз
Нужен такой же эффект как тут (http://ambarcinema.ru/ логотип в левом верхнем углу)

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```js
let scrollVertical = $('html, body');
let imgImageHeader = $('#header .image');

$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    if (scrollVertical.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $(imgImageHeader).stop().animate({
            marginTop: '0%'
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $(imgImageHeader).stop().animate({
            marginTop: '-100%'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 120vh;
    margin: 0px;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;

    background-color: #0DA;
}

#header .image {
    position: inherit;

    min-width: 250px;
    min-height: 250px;
    
    background: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
    <img class="image" src="" alt="">
</div>
```